# SignalR on server side, but native WebSockets connection from client side?

Tags: .net, signalr

If I used SignalR on server side - is it possible to communicate via WebSockets from client side not consuming SignalR libary?

Comment: It is definitely possible, but you would need to do all the plumbing needed to communicate with the SignalR server yourself.

Answer (score 4):

SignalR uses a protocol so that the server and the client can understand each other. You would have to implement this protocol otherwise you would not be able to send and receive messages. Once you implement the protocol you will end up with a SignalR client. [Here](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2015/03/29/signalr-on-the-wire-an-informal-description-of-the-signalr-protocol/)  you can find a description of the SignalR protocol I wrote some time ago. Btw. SignalR C++ client supports only websockets so it's basically what you want to do. It's open source and you can take a look to understand what it takes to implement a SignalR client with just webosckets.

**EDIT**

SignalR for Asp.NET Core allows using bare websockets to connect to the SignalR server.

Comment: It's unclear in the EDIT section. Can you connect using native web sockets without any additional implementation on the client side to support the SignalR? And does the server version matter or is this supported in all server versions that use Asp.Net Core?

Comment: Yes, you can connect with any bare websocket. The caveat is that it works on the non-hub level. Hubs add protocol so you can connect without the client but you need to be able to handle that protocol which is... writing a client. There is only one version at the moment (not counting the pre-release version which are no longer supported given that a stable version was released) so the second question is a moot point.